# wysiwyg image path is {{media url=wysiwyg/eye-tracking-study-by-eyequant.jpg}} but image not found error in console magento 2

Tags: image, magento2.3.4

WYSIWYG image upload from custom module but not sow in frontend .phtml file showing [src="{{media url=wysiwyg/gutenberg-diagram_1.jpg}}" ] like this but image not found and image not show [image]

Link and Iframe also not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to just filter your content like this :

$this->_filterProvider->getPageFilter()->filter($content);

Answer (score 1):

**wysiwyg/gutenberg-diagram_1.jpg** should be under **single quote**.

Like:

```
src="{{media url='wysiwyg/gutenberg-diagram_1.jpg}'}}"
```

Comment: WYSIWYG is default save this format . i was didn't change any things